# PL-SQL Procedure Executes Successfully but doesn't update the table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have written a pl-sql procedure to update a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE EMP_UPDATE (emp IN NUMBER, div_code IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE EMP_CATEGORY 
SET EMP_CATEGORY.DIV_CODE = div_code    
WHERE EMP_CATEGORY.EMP_NO = emp;
    COMMIT;

END EMP_UPDATE;
```

The update query alone works fine and updates the table.But when it's used in the procedure it shows

```
Procedure executed successfully
Query time: 0.018ms
Affected rows: 1
```

but the actual table record doesn't get changed. 
I can't figure out what's wrong with this procedure. Can anyone please point out where have i done the mistake?

Comment: This was closed as too localized. But to me it looks like a wide-spread mistake. The solution is interesting and helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try by changing the input variable name `emp IN NUMBER` to `I_EMP IN NUMBER` or something, because table have a column named `emp`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I don't think that's the problem.I tried that too. I have edited the procedure according to how i changed it.

Comment: Does your table have a column named `DIV_CODE`? If yes, then please rename the variable name `DIV_CODE` to `I_DIV_CODE` or something.

Comment: Yes it has a column with the name DIV_CODE.
And i changed the parameter name to division. And it worked!
Thank you very much for the help!!! (Y) :D